# OleDb - slow reading from Excel

Tags: excel, oledb

I have table with several thousand rows, but even if I try to read 1000 rows (and 10 columns) it takes about 10 second to get result. I think it's too slow, but I can't find any problem.

Code for reading data:

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"", _excelFilename);
using (OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    c.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Trend_Data$A1:J1000]", c);
    OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (dbReader.Read()) {
        object[] values = new object[10];
        dbReader.GetValues(values);

        //save values into internal structure - fast
        ...
    }
```

Stepping through the code I found that calling ExecuteReader function takes so long.

Do you have any ideas, how to speed up code?

Comment: Is your file stored locally? The execution will take a while if on a shared drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [OleDBAdapter Excel QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data/5721521#5721521) I posted via stack overflow.

I took my worksheet from the previous post and added columns (10 total) and rows (10,000 total) and packed it w/ data (the excel file is 1,770 KB).   Using XP w/ 4 cpus, Visual Studio 2010, it takes less than 1 second.

Add this at the top:

```
Stopwatch queryWatch = new Stopwatch();
queryWatch.Start();
```

and this at the bottom:

```
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Query time: {0}.{1} seconds.", queryWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000, queryWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 1000);    
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
Elapsed Query time: 0.623 seconds.
```