# OleDB Can't Retrieve Rows With Different DataType

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, oledb, xls

I am trying to retrieve `DataTable` from .xls file. Below are my code:

```
OleDbConnection MyConnection = null;
DataSet DtSet = null;
OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand = null;
MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

//path is where the .xls file located
ArrayList TblName = new ArrayList();

MyConnection.Open();
DataTable schemaTable = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    TblName.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"]);
}

MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + TblName[0].ToString() + "] order by Material", MyConnection);
DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
MyCommand.FillSchema(DtSet, SchemaType.Source);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DtSet.Tables[0];
MyConnection.Close();
```

Problem is: **I have some inconsistent rows in my table**, meaning **they don't follow the other rows datatype**.

Let's say in column A, I have cells that are supposed to be like:

> 105161610
>
> 146161701
>
> 196171717
>
> .........

Meaning to say it's supposed to be of `Int32` datatype.

These are the majority of the column cells..

I also have some other cells (still in the same column) that look like:

> ABC9012
>
> KDJ0981
>
> KLP0001
>
> .......

They somehow follow `string` datatype.

When I execute the code, I can only `Select` cells of `int` type while cells having the other type (`string`) is set to `null` instead. Although in my code I basically set the `select *` explicitly.

Can someone advise me on how to consistently retrieve both kind of datatype (instead of only 1 like what happens now)?

Comment: I think this might be relevant.

[Importing Excel data containing mixed datatypes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast or convert both types of data to SQL equivalent of string like `varchar`.

Try either one of the following:

```
1. select cast(Column_A as varchar) Column_A from TableName order by Material 
2. select convert(varchar, Column_A) Column_A from TableName order by Material
```

Answer (score 0):

Add excel connection string IMEX=1; HDR={1} like full sting below

Description : IMEX=1  You can force mixed data to be converted to text
HDR={1} indicates that the first row contains column names, not data header row if you dont want then put No