# Changing the datatype of column in datatable changes the cell text

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, I start off by importing an excel file and then save the data into Data table and then putting it into Gridview. I wanted to copy the column header name into a row cell and it was giving error that Input string was not is a correct format. I tried changing the column data type and it works. But the data copied is different to the original. Here is the code I am using:

```
DataTable dtf1 = new DataTable();
 OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
adapter.FillSchema(dtf1, SchemaType.Source);
            dtf1.Columns[6].DataType = typeof(string);
            adapter.Fill(dtf1);

 dtf1.Rows[0][6] = dtf1.Columns[6].ColumnName.ToString();
```

The original data is a postcode number "3210" but it is copying it as something "F7".

Comment: What was the data type originally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here [OleDB & mixed Excel datatypes : missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data/5721521#5721521). The problem was when excel was importing data it was ignoring numbers. Changing the connection string solved the problem.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ServerPath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text'");
```

Previously it was

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ServerPath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1'");
```