# Replace use of excel interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a system which does heavy use of excel interop.
this is problematic , because it is deployed at many client sites,
each with his own unique operating system, office version , regional settings etc...
This causes me headeaches like this one: 
[OleDB & mixed Excel datatypes : missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data/5721521#5721521)

It is hard to reproduce or solve this bugs.
Also, I can't run my system as a windows service, because of known issues with using interops at a windows service.

So what I'm looking for is a tool which will allow me for excel import\export without me using the interop. it should ideally:

1. Support excel 2003 - 2013 and hopefully upcoming versions
2. Support getting values and writing values to excel (of course)
3. Support styling operations (font , range of cells, borders, etc...)
4. Support use of graphs in excel
5. Support macros activation.
6. support csv files

This is all I can think of for now :-)

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I very much doubt there is anything that will support all which you say here without using Excel interop. How is anyone suppose to know the inner workings of Excel ?

Comment: Not used it personally, but Apache POI (possibly NPOI https://code.google.com/p/npoi/ which is a .net port) might work.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, could you please elobrate on how that would solve the issues mentioned above? thanks

Comment: Sure :) Using Latebinding will ensure that your code is compatible with any version of Excel (even future ones). The only difference between LateBinding and EarlyBinding is that you do not set a reference to the Interop Lib beforehand and yet you can access all that you want (points 2-6)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I don't think laste binding would solve problems like dataset import null values (see link in my post). , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office Interop can cause a compatibility problems, you need to have a valid office license installed and... is slow...

Probably the best Open solution is to use the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx). It's well documented and Microsoft encourages the developers to use this approach over Interop.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it does not support excel 2003

Comment: You are right, but if it's not a problem the compatibility pack installed on Office 2003 machines will do the trick http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint-HA010168676.aspx