# in some computers some excel cells return back empty.can you help me?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datagridview

I imported an Excel table to `gridview`. In my own notebook, everything is ok. However, in some notebooks Excel cells return back empty.
I'm using `ASP.NET 4.0` and `Visual C#`

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadExcelInToDataSet
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OleDbConnection oledbConn;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/Table_sverks.xls"));
                if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xls")
                {
                    oledbConn = new   OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xlsx")
                {
                    oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
                }
                oledbConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                oleda.Fill(ds);
                grvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                grvData.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                oledbConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the file isn't exactly the same (~/Table_sverks.xls). Try to return a single value from a known cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same issue in this question 
[OleDB & mixed Excel datatypes : missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data)