# Carriage Return in Table Header

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm writing an Excel macro to pull in data from another Workbook. I don't have any control over that workbook, which is a shame because then I could fix this issue at source, as it is i have to work around it.

There is a column header that starts with a carriage return! and I need to call a select on it.

I've looked around here and found a lot of solutions for when there are carriage returns in the DATA but I can't find anything to deal with them in the header. I've tried to play arround with implementing similar syntax but nothing seems to work. If there is already a solution out there do link me! Maybe I'm just using the wrong terms.

```
sSQL = "SELECT " & _
                "['Dependant Name* (LastName, FirstName (Type))']" & _
           "FROM " & _
                "........" & _
           "WHERE " & _
                "........"
```

So it's a horrible header to start with and it starts with a carriage return!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `select *` work? Do you [have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010213/11683) to use SQL to begin with, given that your code resides in Excel to begin with?

Comment: I can't Select * because there are loads of Headers, I don't need all of them, and the brief I have only calls for a few. I'm also joining two tables so I don't want all headers from both tables!

I'm actually modifying an existing tool to add new features and SQL is the method already in place for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you're connecting to the excel sheet, using ADODB connection, Excel replaces the carriage return with an "_".

So if I had:

`~blank line~
  Field1`

as column name, Excel would give _Field1 as the fieldname for that column.

Alternatively, you could adjust your script to `SELECT * from...` and then in the immediate window `debug.print Recordset.Fields(# of the column the bad header is).Name` to get how Excel is interpreting it and use that value in your select statement.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That worked a treat. I am using ADODB so that line looked like this in the end: `"[_Dependant Name* (LastName, FirstName (Type))]" & _`