# Cannot parse some excel column

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, oledbconnection

Good day!

I try to open and parse excel file into DataSet.

So, i use OleDbConnection:

```
if (_filePath.Substring(_filePath.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            //                 strConn =  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
            //                    + _filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel  12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
             strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
                    + _filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;\"";

        //   strConn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        else
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1\"";
```

But some column are empty!
The next column parses well (it with same data).

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Then i fill Dataset:

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);


            System.Data.DataSet dtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter oleCommand;

            oleCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
            oleCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", sheetName);
            dtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

            oleCommand.Fill(dtSet);
            oleCommand.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            return dtSet.Tables[0];
```

But, some columns are empty!

May be, it happens because excel file has format:

```
 Cell1--------------|Value1------------|
 Cell2---|Cell3-----|Value2---|Value4--|
```

So, dataset fill columns :

```
Cell1---|-------|--Value1------|-----|
Cell2---|Cell3--|---Empty(!)---|Value4|
```

So, i need to get Empty(!) column.

About invalid data at column.

I copy and paste this column at right column- and it works!

But,i should use last format, not mine.

HDR="NO";

Comment: Paste code with actual parsing(whatever You mean by this word). You've just provided the code creating ConnectionString.

Comment: Provide complete code which u r implementing for parsing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you ran into this error:

[OleDB & mixed Excel datatypes : missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data)

What's the value of 'HDR'? Take a look at the Datatypes of the Columns, maybe they are mixed.

Comment: Make a breakpoint after the adapter fills the columns of the dataset, what are the types of the empty columns?

Comment: Name:Double ,another column type- is String

Comment: How to change data type of column to String?