# Getting wrong data type in DataTable read from Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, types, datatable

I'm trying to get datatables from different Excel worksheets. I get the datatables correctly using a `OleDbConnection`. However, some columns are wrongly read as `String`, but some of them are `Double` or `DateTime` type.

The Excel I'm reading I already created it from an Access file and it is written with correct datatypes. I also verified that no "Number stored as text" cell message in the Excel sheet is shown. The problem rise up when I try to read a column in this Excel file which most of the rows are empty.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721521/4074137) I get that ADO.NET chooses the data type based on the majority of the values in the column. So I don't know if the fact that most of the entries are empty in these fields could affect while reading it.

But, I repeat, this does not happen when reading the datatable content from the Access because the field in the Access design is defined with corresponding `DataType` while in the Excel it is not.

This is my function to get the desired worksheet content as `DataTable`:

```
Public Function GetDatatable(sheetName As String, versionFilter As String) As DataTable
    Try
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim dbSource As String = String.Format("Data Source={0};", Trim(IExcelValue))
        Dim dbProperties As String = "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
        'Set version filter string if needed
        If Not versionFilter Is Nothing Then
            versionFilter = String.Format(" where numversion = '{0}'", versionFilter)
        Else
            versionFilter = ""
        End If
        'Set the connection string
        Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", dbProvider, dbSource, dbProperties)
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("select * from [{0}$]{1}", sheetName, versionFilter), MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", sheetName)
        ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(ds)
        MyConnection.Close()
        GetDatatable = ds.Tables(sheetName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

I know which fields must be `Double`, `DateTime` or `String` and I can loop over those columns and assign the correct `DataType`, but that's not elegant.

So, I suppose that the default `DataType` of specific field if most of the records are empty in a `DataTable` while reading from Excel worksheet is `String` type. How could I manage to get the correct `DataType` in these cases?

(I don't know if it is important or not, but I'm using [Closed XML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) to write the Excel file)