# Speed up query from table using ADO and SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I have an Excel macro that reads data from another file using ADO and SQL. 
It runs fine but it takes too long

Here is the part of the code that connects to the other file.

```
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Properties("Data Source") = "W:\Store.xlsm"
    .Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
    .Open OpenForwardOnly, LockReadOnly, CmdText
End With

Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT `main$`.`" & MasterField & "`  FROM `main$` `main$` WHERE `main$`.Num= '" & Hyperion & "'")

Master = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

Thank you!

Comment: How long does it take, and how long do you expect it to take?

Comment: It takes about 10 seconds, under 3 would be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using .xlsb copy of the file.

Comment: .Thank you. Not making any difference. Only the file size changed.

Comment: Another thing, see answer here about data types, headings and casting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data/

Comment: No difference either